# What part of this one-line script is specific to zsh?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I wrote a simple program called `sarcasm` that simply takes all its arguments, concatenates them, and converts the resulting string use 'aLtErNaTiNg CaPs'. I have written a simple one-line shell script that will let me use dmenu to enter text, run that text through this program, and copy the result to my clipboard. Here is what I have:

```
echo "dmenu -p 'Text: '" | sh | read var ; [[ -n "$var" ]] && echo -n $var | xargs sarcasm | xclip -selection clipboard
```

It is supposed to:

- Prompt me for text using dmenu
- If (and only if) I entered any text, run it through the `sarcasm` program and copy the result to my clipboard

It works fine when I run that exact command with zsh, or if I run it in a script using zsh (i.e. the shebang is `#!/bin/zsh`), but when I run it with bash, it doesn't copy anything to my clipboard. What part of this is zsh-only, and what is the bash equivalent (if there is one)?

Comment: It's all POSIX shell (except for `[[ .. ]]` which is irrelevant) - nothing is zsh specific. I suspect your ENVIRONMENT is different when you run from bash and it does not have the X environment present (this is a strong suspicion, but cannot be verified without seeing your environment)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `[[` is not POSIX, but it is a legal bash operator.

Comment: @ShaneBishop  Good eye -- updated.

Comment: We might need to see the contents of `sarcasm` to identify the issue. Or it could be something with your environment. Have you tried `echo -n 'test' | xclip -selection clipboard` with an interactive bash shell, to try to rule things out?

Comment: See also [man 1 xclip](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/xclip/xclip.1.en) the `DISPLAY` variable must be set in the environment. You can add the `-v` option to `xclip` for additional details on what is happening.

Comment: For instance, `echo $var` may produce slightly different results. Say `var` contains the text `A     B` (4 embedded spaces) , then it would produce `A     B` under zsh, but `A B` (1 space) under bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part:

```sh
echo "dmenu -p 'Text: '" | sh | read var 
# ............................^^^^^^^^^^
```

In bash, each command in a pipeline is run in a separate subshell. Because the `var` variable is set in a subshell, the variable vanishes when the subshell exits.

To execute that in bash, redirect the output of a process substitution: this way, the `read` command runs in the current shell.

```sh
read -r var < <(dmenu -p 'Text: ')
```

I imagine that would work in zsh too.

There is another workaround: set the `lastpipe` setting and disable job control

```sh
$ echo foo | read var; declare -p var
bash: declare: var: not found

$ set +o monitor
$ shopt -s lastpipe
$ echo foo | read var; declare -p var
declare -- var="foo"
```

Comment: Your first suggestion, redirecting the output of process substitution, worked! Thanks so much!